# Label in frame not showing | Python | Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to build a menu for my application and in the menu bar, I have options for 'About me' and 'help page' under the help tab and the main menu in the File tab.

I'm creating Frames for the 'About me' and the 'help page' which should display relevant text upon clicking, and the main menu takes us to the 'main page'.

The issue I'm facing is that when I'm placing 'label text' in the 'help page', the main application screen displays that text, and the frame doesn't appear if choosing the 'help page' frame as a container. If I choose app(TK instance) as a container, permanent text displays even upon forgetting frames.

Here's the snippet:-

```
# Create window object
app = Tk()
##getting screen width and height of display
wide= app.winfo_screenwidth()
long= app.winfo_screenheight()

#setting tkinter window size
app.geometry("%dx%d" % (wide, long))
def aboutme():
    hide_frames()
    aboutme_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

def helppage():
    hide_frames()
    var = StringVar()
    label = Label(app, textvariable=var, relief=RAISED,bg='blue')

    var.set("Hey!? How are you doing?")
    label.grid(row=0,column=0)
    help_page.grid(row=0,column=0)


def mainmenu():
    hide_frames()

def hide_frames():
    aboutme_frame.grid_forget()
    help_page.grid_forget()
##Menu bar
menubar = Menu(app)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Main Menu",command=mainmenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=app.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="Help Index",command=helppage)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About...",command= aboutme)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

app.config(menu=menubar)

## Create frames
aboutme_frame = Frame(app,width=wide,height=long,bg='grey')
help_page = Frame(app,width=wide,height=long,bg='black')
# Start program
app.mainloop()
```

EDIT--
Added full program (part where Tkinter is being used)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a complete example. The code you posted doesn't create a root window or call any of those functions.

Comment: @BryanOakley Done, edited so it might be more clear now..!

Comment: You are adding your Label directly to the root window, rather than either Frame.  Hiding/showing Frames will have no effect on it.

Comment: @jasonharper I tried label = Label(help_page , textvariable=var, relief=RAISED,bg='blue') command too but I only gets text on main screen and not on black background frame

Comment: How do you tell the difference?  A Frame with one child widget is not normally going to show *any* of its own background color, it will shrink to fit the child.

Comment: @jasonharper Frame grid fills screen see: (help_page = Frame(app,width=wide,height=long,bg='black'))
Same dimension as window app and background black,text should be added on that screen (atleast that's what I'm looking forward to)

Comment: `width=` and `height=` only affect a Frame with no children.  You can call `.grid_propagate(False)` (or `.pack_propagate`) to override that, but normally it's best to let the geometry manager actually do its job.

Comment: @jasonharper Any workaround if I want text on my Frame, basically I want help page from menu to display some text regarding application and text on Frame was my best bet

Comment: Try this label.place(y=10,x=10) instead of label.grid(row=0,column=0)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @toyota Supra for suggestion.

I was doing two mistakes basically, first invoking another grid for label and second placing label on grid without initializing frame grid hence I was seeing Label on main screen itself.
Here's changes I made that worked..!

```
def helppage():
    hide_frames()
    var = StringVar()
    help_page.grid(row=0,column=0)
    help_label = Label(help_page, textvariable=var, relief=RAISED,bg='blue')
    var.set("Hey!? How are you doing?")
    help_label.place(relx = 0.5,
                   rely = 0.5,
                   anchor = 'center')
```

Comment: It is my pleasure to solve the problem.